# Change Photo Opacity When Link Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to make a gallery of photos with their Categories on top of them. How can i make specific photos opacity increase(or decrease) when their category link is clicked? Im not sure whether I can achieve this with css only.  Every help is appreciated

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class mapper for each category. It's not a very generic solution with CSS only but at least it gets the job done.

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sports">sports</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cats">cats</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fashion">fashion</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="technics">technics</a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract" class="abstract" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city" class="city" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people" class="people" alt="" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/fashion" class="fashion" alt="" />
</div>
```

Map classes from anchor to image. In CSS3 you can use the `~` tilde selector.

**CSS**

```
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
a.abstract:active ~ img.abstract,
a.abstract:focus ~ img.abstract {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/E3Tjg/)

If this approach is not flexible enough you might consider a JavaScript solution.

**UPDATE**

A combination of the hidden input and the class mapper. Please note the behavior is now more of toggle functionality. You can change the type of the input field to `radio` (and proper `name` attribute) to match the behavior to my previous demo.

THE trick is to use the labels to trigger the input fields. The placement of the input fields should be inside the image container so you can use the `~` selector in CSS.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/b8U72/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thats a great example, however the problem is that my menu is put inside a list in a different div from where the photos are. Any ideas?

Comment: The hidden checkbox solution from misterManSam is the best approach for more complex HTML structure if you combine it with my solution. Other than that as suggested => JavaScript solution.

Comment: Also, you should've provided the HTML so I'm not wasting time on a solution that perfectly answers your question ... but not representative for your HTML I know nothing about. Usually it will gain you downvotes and frustration. FYI

Comment: I'm Sorry Tim, my bad, i forgot. This / is how my html looks like http://jsfiddle.net/GranitS/9bZm6/3

Comment: Just check the update, you didn't see that? :s

Comment: Sorry for being such a pain in the ass, it is the perfect solution. Thank you

Comment: That's quite alright, glad you like it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something quite fun :)

Pure CSS!

**Improved with checked "link" state**

1. The label can be made to look like a link and will change when selected.
2. The label is connected to the checkbox with the matching `for` and `id` attribute.
3. Checkbox is hidden with `display: none;`
4. The order of HTML elements is important.

[Have an improved fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/SrA55/1/)

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="linkOne" />
<div class="category">
    <label for="linkOne">Category One (click me)</label>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .category img {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    opacity:0.5;
}
input[type=checkbox] + .category img {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    opacity:1;
}
label:hover { 
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
}
label {
    display: block;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .category label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, thats an awesome checkbox trick btw. However my Categories are put in a list, in a different div from where the photos are supposed to go. Ive tried modifying your code to fill my needs but couldnt get to the result i wanted. Any advice?

Comment: Haha, well this could be pushing the CSS only route, but it is possible with absolute positioning depending on how you want it to lay out... [Have a look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/SrA55/2/)

Comment: This is how my html looks like http://jsfiddle.net/GranitS/9bZm6/3/. Ive tried all options on how to reference photos if clicked, but no luck. Probably js must be used here

Comment: JS is the way to go. [CSS is still possible though](http://jsfiddle.net/SrA55/4/) :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jquery fadeTo function

example from [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)

```
<div id="clickme">
  Click here
</div>
<img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">
// With the element initially shown, we can dim it slowly:
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0.5, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

or you could use simple css

```
img {
    opacity:1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: the reverse of the css given will increase the opacity

Comment: javascript solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2972/Changing-the-opacity-transparency-of-images-using