# Sass - How do I select a label of a radio input?

Tags: css, input, sass

I'm attempting to apply a background color to a radio button's label when it's in the :checked state.

Edit: This is essentially what I'm trying to achieve, but with multiple selections: 
https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3706/expandable-elements.html

Below I have the full markup. What I can't seem to get working right is:

```
label

  &:hover
    text-decoration: underline
    cursor: pointer

  &:checked
    background: white
    color: blue
```

I've tried a few different techniques like adding a selector to `#shop + label`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Cheers.

**html**

```
<!-- Menu -->
<ul class="nav-p">
<li><label for="shop">Shop</label></li>
<li><label for="support">Support</label></li>
<li><label for="mystuff">myStuff</label></li>
</ul>

<!-- Sub Menu -->
<input type="radio" id="shop" name="menu">
<ul class="nav-s">
<li>Shop - 1</li>
<li>Shop - 2</li>
<li>Shop - 3</li>
</ul>

<input type="radio" id="support" name="menu">
<ul class="nav-s">
<li>Support - 1</li>
<li>Support - 2</li>
<li>Support - 3</li>
</ul>

<input type="radio" id="mystuff" name="menu">
<ul class="nav-s">
<li>myStuff - 1</li>
<li>myStuff - 2</li>
<li>myStuff - 3</li>   
</ul>
```

**Sass**

```
.nav-p
        +clearfix

        li
          list-style: none
          float: left
          display: block
          padding: 12px 15px 15px 15px
          margin-top: 3px
          +border-top-radius(3px)

          color: white
          font:
            size: 15px
            weight: 100

          label

            &:hover
              text-decoration: underline
              cursor: pointer
            &:checked
              background: white
              color: blue

#shop + .nav-s
  display: none

#shop
  display: none
  &:checked + .nav-s
    display: block

#support + .nav-s
  display: none

#support
  display: none
  &:checked + .nav-s
    display: block

#mystuff + .nav-s
  display: none

#mystuff
  display: none

  &:checked + label
    background: blue

  &:checked + .nav-s
    display: block


.nav-s
  background: white
  +border-bottom-radius(5px)
  padding: 5px 10px

  li
    list-style: none
    display: inline-block
    padding: 10px
    color: $linkColor

    &:hover
      cursor: pointer
      text-decoration: underline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `:checked` state on a `label`, only on the corresponding `input` field.

So you should move your input field to the same DOM level as your labels.

```
<label for="myId"></label>
<input id= "myId" type="radio" />
```

Then on the CSS part you can do:

```
label + input:checked
    background-color: #f00;
```

If for some reason you can't change the HTML structure, the only solution left is JavaScript.

See a [similar technique here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716751/change-photo-opacity-when-link-clicked/24717609#24717609) with the `~` operator

Comment: I'm able to select the sibling of the :checked radio input using for: 'ID' to navigate to it in the DOM. Is there not a way to navigate back?

Comment: No, only to the selector and/or to an x amount of level depth. But the `+` and `~` are bound to the same level. You can't go back, up in the tree, so to speak.